# Object is nil when called from another class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to change properties of another object, when a method is called in another class.

The code to change the properties of this object sits in a method of the first class, and works when calling it from it's own class, but when called from the other class the object in the method returns nil.

*Here is the code:*

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    UIView *menuView; //the object

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *menuView;

-(void)closeMenu; //the method

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize menuView;

-(void)closeMenu{

    [menuView setFrame:CGRectMake(menuView.frame.origin.x, -menuView.frame.size.height, menuView.frame.size.width, menuView.frame.size.height)];

    NSLog(@"%f", menuView.frame.size.height); //returns height when method is called from it's own class. But returns 0 (nil) when called from the other class.

}
```

**SDNestedTableViewController.h** (nothing too important, but might help?)

```
@interface SDMenuViewController : SDNestedTableViewController{


}
```

**SDNestedTableViewController.m**

```
#import "SDMenuViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

- (void) item:(SDGroupCell *)item subItemDidChange:(SDSelectableCell *)subItem
{

    ViewController *firstViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    SelectableCellState state = subItem.selectableCellState;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [item.subTable indexPathForCell:subItem];
    switch (state) {
        case Checked:
            NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Checked\"", indexPath);


            [firstViewController closeMenu]; //called from other class


            break;
        case Unchecked:
            NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Unchecked\"", indexPath);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize menuView?

Comment: @user427969 how do you mean? I made it in Interface Builder

Comment: This is a standard question.  You need to understand the difference between a class and an object.

Comment: @SirKaydian Sorry I didn't saw IBOutlet.

Comment: @HotLicks then what am I doing wrong? how is this achieved..?

Comment: 1st check the connection of IBOutlet & 2nd check  whether viewdidload is getting called & print the menuview frame if the menuframe are returning 0 then There is some problem in connection type.

Comment: Check if the viewDidLoad in ViewController is getting called before the [firstViewController closeMenu]; If yes, then try to print the value of menuView in an NSLog and update the question. Also why dont you try to use initWithNib instead just init?

Comment: @SirKaydian, why don't you want to try my solution?

Comment: Is there a FirstViewController that exists before your `item:subItemDidChange:` method is called that you're meaning to interact with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2:

Well, you shipped your code over to me, so now I can no longer say that I don't have enough information to solve your problem.

Let's see.

Now I see that your ViewController is the rootViewController of your app, like so:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Good, now how does the ViewController relate to your SDNestedTableViewController?

You have this in your ViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SDMenuViewController *mvc = [[[SDMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SDNestedTableView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    [self addChildViewController:mvc];
    [mvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [menuView addSubview:mvc.view];

    // Some other stuff with gesture recognizers I'm omitting...

    [self openMenu];

}
```

Alright, so it looks like SDMenuViewController is the child of ViewController.  Now, you have a method in SDMenuViewController called item:subItemDidChange:

```
- (void) item:(SDGroupCell *)item subItemDidChange:(SDSelectableCell *)subItem
{

    ViewController *firstViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

    SelectableCellState state = subItem.selectableCellState;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [item.subTable indexPathForCell:subItem];
    switch (state) {
        case Checked:
            NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Checked\"", indexPath);

            //close the menuView

            [firstViewController closeMenu];

            break;
        case Unchecked:
            NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Unchecked\"", indexPath);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

So, you want the reference back to the *existing* ViewController object, right?  Because right there you're making another one.  So, you can do this:

```
ViewController *firstViewController = self.parentViewController;
```

That gets you a reference to SDMenuViewController's parent, which is the instance of ViewController.  This property is set when you do your `addChildViewController:` call.

---

Okay, this is confusing though:

In your post, you say that your `item:subItemDidChange:` method is in SDNestedTableViewController, but in the code you sent me it's in the SDMenuViewController.

In the SDNestedTableViewController, I found this method:

```
- (void) mainItem:(SDGroupCell *)item subItemDidChange: (SDSelectableCell *)subItem forTap:(BOOL)tapped
{
    if(delegate != nil && [delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(item:subItemDidChange:)] )
    {
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(item:subItemDidChange:) withObject:item withObject:subItem];
    }
}
```

So it looks like you're not using the same code as in the original post, but close enough, whatever.

---

Now, if you want to get a reference to the ViewController instance from *anywhere* in the app, not just your SDMenuViewController (which happens to be the child of the ViewController instance) you should use @Mathew Varghese's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13118017/700471).

Here's a restatement of this method:

1. Add the line `+ (AppDelegate *)instance;` to your AppDelegate.h file.
2. Add the following method to your AppDelegate.m file.

Like so:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)instance
{
    AppDelegate *dg = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    return dg;
}
```

Then, in whatever object you want that reference, you `#import AppDelegate.h` and say `ViewController *vc = AppDelegate.instance.firstViewController;`

Anyway, it's just another way of saying what Mathew mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank to very much for this answer. I will be trying it out, then get back to you.

Answer (score 4):

What you posted looks like:

```
-(void)closeMenu{
    // menuView is never initialized, == nil
    [nil setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -0, 0, 0)];

    NSLog(@"%f", 0); //returns height when method is called from it's own class. But returns 0 (nil) when called from the other class.

}
```

So you are doing `NSLog(@"%f", 0);`.

If you do load the view by accessing the `view` property, the menuView will be initialized by IB rules.
For the details of viewController view loading/unloading see the [reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html).

Comment: but it works if I do `[self closeMenu]` in the ViewController class... returns the objects height... I think you misunderstood the comment

Comment: In fact that is you who misunderstands your test-cases. And I don't feel any intent to help you anymore.

Comment: okay, I understand where you're coming from. But it's not always nil. Only when called from another class. How do I change this..?

Comment: `[MyViewController new].myoutlet` is always nil. `id a = [MyViewController new]; a.view; a.myoutlet;` is not nil. Back to study: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html

Comment: The important thing here is that you have `alloc/init`'d the VC, but you have NOT added it to a view, so `viewDidLoad` etc haven't run, which is why your `IBOutlet` is nil. @A-Live, you might want to make that a bit clearer in your answer.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `viewDidLoad` gets called when you access viewController's `view` property for the 1st time (thus asking the UIViewController to create/load its view) so it _may_ help to access `firstViewController.view` somewhere in between it's creation and the call to `closeMenu`. However, a better idea would be to introduce some boolean property in your ViewController class that you can set right after its alloc+init and either display the menu or not in ViewController's `viewDidLoad` depending on whether that property is set.

Comment: @Micahel, I was a little upset to get uncommented downvote for the answer that only requires a little research from OP, but I see the point and I'm going to add the docs reference from the comment to the answer in case somebody else will find it useful. Please feel free to add your own answer quoting the document if you find that is a way to go, I'm not interested in bounty for this question at all.

Comment: You don't understand. The ViewController does load. It's the first thing to load. menuView is created right when the app starts running. And I can access it `[self closeMenu];` and it works. I know that it is not nil. But then even after I do that. I move onto the other class file, and it doesn't work. It gets to the method but then BAM it's nil. I go back to the other class file, and BAM it works again. It must be something with the way I call it. Or maybe you just can't do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @SirKaydian I'm going to explain it to you one more time. The view is **NOT** loaded as you are initializing the viewController just 5 lines above the `closeMenu` call, you have **never** called it's `view` outlet to make the view loaded. That is a **complete** explanation of why `menuView` is `nil`. Another problem you have is that the viewController's view you are calling `closeMenu` for is NEVER displayed, you were probably using **another** `ViewController` instance's view to display.

Comment: Ahh. The last thing you said does strike a bell. The class that I am trying (and failing) to  call `closeMenu` does not have a XIB file along with it. Is *this* the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think this may help you.

At Your `AppDelegate` class, you have to declare an object of `ViewController` class. Make it as a property of the `YourAppDelegate` class. like below. (This would import `ViewController` class and creates a shared object of `YourAppDelegate` class so that you can access the members of `YourAppDelegate` class globally by simply importing the `YourAppDelegate.h`).

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#define UIAppDelegate ((YourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)

@interface YourAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> 
{
     ViewController  *objViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController  *objViewController;

@end
```

And synthesize the property at `YourAppDelegate.m` file.

```
@implementation YourAppDelegate

@synthesize objViewController;

@end
```

Then the tricky part is, you have to backup the object of `ViewController` class in the `YourAppDelegate` class at the time you are loading the `ViewController` class.

For that first import the `YourAppDelegate.h` in the `ViewController.h` class and at the `ViewController.m` implement `viewWillAppear:` delegate as follows.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    UIAppDelegate.objViewController = self;
}
```

Then at `SDNestedTableViewController.m`,

```
#import "SDMenuViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

- (void) item:(SDGroupCell *)item subItemDidChange:(SDSelectableCell *)subItem
{

    ViewController *firstViewController = (ViewController *)UIAppDelegate.objViewController;

    if(firstViewController && [firstViewController isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]])
    {
            SelectableCellState state = subItem.selectableCellState;
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [item.subTable indexPathForCell:subItem];
            switch (state) {
              case Checked:
                        NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Checked\"", indexPath);


                        [firstViewController closeMenu]; //called from other class


                        break;
              case Unchecked:
                        NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Unchecked\"", indexPath);
                        break;
              default:
                        break;
            }
    }
}
```

Try this way. I am not saying this as the right way but, this should works. Glad if this helps you.

Comment: Tried this, but came up with the error that AppDelegate.objViewController is `not found on object of type AppDelegate`

Comment: its `UIAppDelegate` no? if you are renamed it as `AppDelegate` then its ok. But remember to import the your project's appdelegate class where ever you use the shared object. Or can you plz share your code so that i can understand the problem better.

Comment: i think you are misleaded with the `AppDelegate`. i meant it as appdelegate class in your project. here you can see it named as `YourAppDelegate`.

Comment: This answer seems a bit off the wall; I don't see how this has anything to do with the problem.  Without really knowing anything about the app structure in question (as Kaydian hasn't really provided enough information) you want him to put a reference to his `ViewController` object in the UIAppDelegate?  His reference from the SDMenuViewController to the firstViewController may be perfectly valid, depending on what his view controller hierarchy is.

Comment: @MattMc: I disagree. I'm betting this answer is right on the money. It sounds like SirKaydian has an existing ViewController instance that he means to talk to, but he's creating a new instance instead. That view controller is never hooked up to anything, so it seems pretty much guaranteed that's where the mistake is, and the mistake of accidentally creating two view controllers where you mean to have one is a very common culprit.

Comment: @Chuck: You may be right, that SirKaydian means to talk to an existing instance of ViewController, and now I see that was what Mathew Varghese was trying to correct. On the other hand, Kaydian hasn't provided enough info for anyone to know that an AppDelegate reference is the way to go, over a direct reference or a delegate or anything. I think it's wrong to prescribe this kind of complex change, especially without explaining it, when the problem isn't actually understood. Clearly Kaydian had trouble implementing it.

Comment: @MattMc (as well as Chuck, and OP ) would you like me to upload a link to the program? I believe that this answer is most likely right.

Comment: @MattMc here it is. Thanks. http://www.speedyshare.com/yGrRx/CrunchCalculator-1-2.zip

Answer (score 1):

the problem is:

```
- (void) item:(SDGroupCell *)item subItemDidChange:(SDSelectableCell *)subItem {

    ViewController *firstViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    ...

    [firstViewController closeMenu];


}
```

When you call `closeMenu` from there, it is never initialized, because not enough time has passed to initialize `view` of view controller, `viewDidLoad` method of your `firstViewController` is not called at this point either. `menuView` is not created from nib either, so this is the reason why it is `nil`.

Maybe for some reason there might be a delay long enough so `menuView` is created, but this is not how you should do things in iOS.

So, if you don't want to show your `menuView`, just add some boolean value to your `firstViewController` and instead of `closeMenu` do:

```
firstViewController.shouldCloseMenu = YES;
```

Then in your `ViewController` in `viewDidLoad` method do something like:

```
if (self.shouldCloseMenu ) {
    [self closeMenu];
}
```

Maybe this is not the best way to do it, but now you have an idea how it suppose to work.

Comment: But the viewDidLoad method has been called. I made sure of that.

Comment: are you definitely sure that it has been called **before** you call `closeMenu`? I recommend you to try my code, I am pretty sure that there might be racings in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem is the related to the way you have initialized the viewController.

Instead of

```
ViewController *firstViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
```

use

```
ViewController *firstViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNibName" bundle:nil] autorelease];
```

I'm assuming you have a nib because you are using an IBOutlet. But I believe the IBOutlet is never setup because you have not loaded the nib file.

Also double check your IBOutlet connection with interface builder and use "self.menuView"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to solve this problem in the following steps.

1. Do not use any instance or variable of `firstViewController` in the `SDMenuViewController`.
2. In the case check block, post a message to the `NSNotificationCenter`
3. In the `ViewController` register the message with the same message Id, use the `closeMenu` method as its handler.

For me, use the message center to dispatch the handling can decouple the relationship between controllers. This is a better way that you would concern less about the lifecycle of the controller within another one.

Hope it would be helpful.

Comment: Nothing in the question poster's code indicates that use of NSNotificationCenter would be beneficial; you are advocating it for no apparent reason.  In his code, he creates (owns) a `ViewController` object.  There is no reason why he should not use that reference to it.  If you are suggesting that his pattern of creating the `ViewController` in that method is incorrect, say so please, in detail.  Additionally, if you want to introduce the subject of notifications to someone, I suggest linking to the appropriate Apple docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `alloc-init`'ing a ViewController and `alloc-init`'ing that view controller's properties.

Regarding your second example (calling from another class). Your current code indicates that you `alloc-init` firstViewController, but then don't do anything with it. Assuming you have not overriden your ViewController's `init` method, its properties and iVars should be `nil` (or undefined at worst). You need to `alloc-init` your `firstViewController.menuView` first. I.e:

```
firstViewController.menuView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame]; // Don't do this.
```

The problem with this approach is that you're setting up firstViewController's properties form another class, and that's generally fairly average design practice. This required setup would usually happen in `viewDidLoad` but because you haven't done anything with firstViewController yet, it never gets called.

In contrast, when you call `closeMenu` from its own View Controller, the odds are you are actually doing something with the view and viewDidLoad (or wherever `menuView = [[UIView alloc] init];`is found) is called first, thus initialising your menuView object.

You need to ensure that your menuView object is initialised first before you try and do anything with it, just initialising the View Controller that contains it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "SDMenuViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

- (void) item:(SDGroupCell *)item subItemDidChange:(SDSelectableCell *)subItem
{
```

> // why are we allocating this object here, if it is only required in case Checked :

```
    ViewController *firstViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    SelectableCellState state = subItem.selectableCellState;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [item.subTable indexPathForCell:subItem];
    switch (state) {
        case Checked:
            NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Checked\"", indexPath);


            [firstViewController closeMenu]; //called from other class


            break;
        case Unchecked:
            NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Unchecked\"", indexPath);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Change it to

```
#import "SDMenuViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

- (void) item:(SDGroupCell *)item subItemDidChange:(SDSelectableCell *)subItem
{
```

> // why are we allocating this object here, if it is only required in case Checked :

```
    SelectableCellState state = subItem.selectableCellState;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [item.subTable indexPathForCell:subItem];
    switch (state) {
        case Checked:
            NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Checked\"", indexPath);


            // here no need to put object in autorelease mode.
            ViewController *firstViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
            [firstViewController closeMenu]; //called from other class
            [firstViewController release];

            break;
        case Unchecked:
            NSLog(@"Changed Sub Item at indexPath:%@ to state \"Unchecked\"", indexPath);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct, change the **-(void)closeMenu** method like...

```
-(void)closeMenu
{
    menuView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.0,50.0,200.0,200.0)]
    NSLog(@"%f", menuView.frame.size.height); //returns height when method is called from it's own class. But returns 0 (nil) when called from the other class.
}
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: I changed in CGRectMake(); Because menuView is "nil". So we have to give the values directly.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove **UIView *menuView; //the object** from the interface file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    // try to remove this line
    UIView *menuView; //the object

}
```

and update this method

```
-(void)closeMenu{

    [self.menuView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.menuView.frame.origin.x, -self.menuView.frame.size.height, self.menuView.frame.size.width, self.menuView.frame.size.height)];

    NSLog(@"%f", self.menuView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use this:

```
if(menuView) {
    [menuView setFrame:CGRectMake(menuView.frame.origin.x, -menuView.frame.size.height, menuView.frame.size.width, menuView.frame.size.height)];
} else {
    NSLog(@"menuView is nil");
}
```